# How to Continue Scraping to next array(i) if one return "Failed to Open Steam"

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping

I am using Curl method to check HTTP response before scraping.

```
foreach($URls as $URL){
if($response($URL)==200){
    $html= new \Htmldom($URL);}}
```

But sometimes as(the SERVER response 404), Loop stops, I want it to continue(Move to next one)
even one of pages returns as fails.

I am using Laravel Yanqi HTMLDom Parser

Comment: I am able to solve this problem by using SHUTUP operator ,
if( $html= @ new \Htmldom($URL))!==FALSE

The loop continues to next .. That made my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to user `try{}catch{}` blocks to continue your looping process. Below is the example for this.

```
foreach($URls as $URL) {
   try{
      if($response($URL)==200) {
         $html= new \Htmldom($URL);
      }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
      // can catch exception
    }
}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: It would be Better to use @

Answer (score 1):

Add an else to it:

```
foreach($URls as $URL){
    if($response($URL)==200){
        $html= new \Htmldom($URL);
    } else {
        continue;
    } 
}
```

Comment: The Problems seems to be NOT in that case you mentioned since if I add else, It won't do anything except it would turn to ELSE statement if IF condition fails. I don't want to do ANYTHING if the condition of IF fails..


Sometimes While checking response it return 200 Response and when it turns to next condition which is  $html= new \Htmldom($URL); Another request is sent for which It recives 404 NOT found (Because server deny Requests.) @Janno